# How can I get a message to show up only when screen is shrunk on the browser?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a message to show up only when the screen is shrunk. I don't understand why what I'm doing is not working. What's happening is the message is being applied at all times rather than only when screen is shrunk. I can see the css show up in my source file , but I don't see my css rule being applied.

**css**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .invisibleMessage: {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

**html**

```
<p class='invisibleMessage'>Only visible on mobile</p>
```

Comment: You want the opposite of what you're doing. Set the display to none fall all cases and then on small screens set it to block

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I posted this, I realized I was simply including a colon that I shouldn't be there after '.invisibleMessage'
Also should be min-width

Answer (score 0):

**CSS is supposed to be like this :**

```
 .invisibleMessage {
    display: none;
 } 

 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .invisibleMessage {
      display: block;
    }
  }
```